# height: 100% of remaining space in element with fixed height

Tags: css

I've absolute positioned div with an fixed height and hidden overflow. I want to place an list thus height shall be 100% of the remaining height. I want to do this with pure CSS. Is this possible?

[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doyGYP)

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    // ...  
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.parent ul{
  background: green;
}
```

Here's an simple image showing what I mean by 100% of the remaining height.
[image]

Comment: You say 100% of the remaining height but remaining after what? The list is the only child of that div.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want it to do? if you want it to scroll then try this

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: red;
} 
.parent ul {
  background: green;
}
```